# Ggplot is not able to be run by R?

Tags: r

I am training on diamonds set, I don't thing it is impossible to be runned by R

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data = diamonds[diamonds$carat<3.1], method = 'lm', color ='red')
```

any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(data = diamonds[diamonds$carat<3.1,], method = 'lm', color ='red')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: holy..i see what I did there. Been stuck for a while, too much for today. Thanks :)

Comment: @rainbowthug Always a pleasure helping you, if you consider this answer helped, consider potentially accepting it. Kin regards!

Comment: Can you guide me how to accept it? I've alreday clicked the up arrow which says "this answer is useful". I am new to stackoverflow as the user